# Passing Values from Calling PHP script to Called PHP script

Tags: php

So I have this Page Builder Class:

```
<?php
class PageBuilderService {
    public function getHeader() {
        // return file_get_contents('template/header.html');
        include 'template/header.php';
    }

    public function getFooter() {
        return file_get_contents('template/footer.html');
    }
}
?>
```

In a PHP page it gets called like so:

```
$page_builder = new PageBuilderService();
```

Then where I want the page header I call:

```
$page_builder->getHeader();
```

Etc etc.

But I want to add a scripts function that will pull in a `scripts.php` file which will run through a list of script file names passed to it in order display `<script>` tags on a page.

Scipts php file:

```
<?php
    $page_builder = new PageBuilderService();

    echo $page_builder::createScriptTags($listOfScripts);
?>
```

So obviously this means extending my `PageBuilderService` class:

```
<?php
class PageBuilderService {
    public function getHeader() {
        // return file_get_contents('template/header.html');
        include 'template/header.php';
    }

    public function getFooter() {
        return file_get_contents('template/footer.html');
    }

    public function getScripts() {

            include 'template/scripts.php'; // Maybe here the list of scripts can be injected?
    }

    public static function createScriptTags($listOfScripts) {
        $scriptHtml = "";
        foreach ($listOfScripts as $script) {
            // some html building
        }

        return $scriptHtml;
    }
}
?>
```

What is the best way to get the `$listOfScripts` from a PHP page to the scripts php file?

Would something like `$_GLOBAL[]` be the best way?

The outcome would be something like:

```
$page_builder->getScripts(); // and some way of getting a list of scripts to the script page
```

Ideally, I would like:

```
$scriptsToInclude = array("neededJsFile.js", "someOtherJs.js");
echo $page_builder->getScripts($scriptsToInclude);
```

But obviously it depends on what is possible.

Comment: Where will you be including your scripts? in the head?

Comment: at the foot of the HTML page ideally!

Comment: don't return your values. save them in a static variable you can manipulate. with your current design, i don't think you have much flexibility.

Comment: could you expand on that?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your Ideally, i would like... snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @DragonYen said, setting up a variable in script a, then calling script b and accesing said variable works. So I will create an array of scripts to include

```
$scriptsToInclude = array("script1.js", "script2.js");
```

Then call the script php

```
echo $page_builder->getScripts();
```

Then in the script php, check the `$scriptsToInclude` variable for scripts and build if there are any

```
if (!empty($scriptsToInclude) && count($scriptsToInclude) > 0) {
   PageBulderService::createScriptTags($scriptsToInclude);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
class PageBuilderService {
    private $aScripts = array();        

    public function addScript($cScript) {
        $this->aScripts[$cScript] = true;
    }

    public static function createScriptTags() {
        $scriptHtml = "";
        foreach ($this->aScripts as $script) {
            // some html building
        }

        return $scriptHtml;
    }
}
```

This way you could add a different number of scripts dynamically based on the code, but they would all be injected when you called createScriptTags... or am I missing the real question?

Comment: but when you populate `$aScripts` in the php file surely it gets lost once you get to the scripts.php file?

Comment: @No1_Melman whats in scripts.php? Including a php file within a class method is odd, unless its just templating, i would add the code directly to the method

Comment: Ahh... sorry, now I understand your question. You are wondering about the scope of "$page_builder" when you get to the scripts.php file. -- I just tried this with a simple "1.php" and "2.php" set a var in 1.php and printed it in 2.php. It does actually work. However I have to agree with the points made by user574632

Comment: Personally i like html helper classes to be simple collections of static methods. If they need to be instance objects, they are probably badly designed, and are doing things that should be elsewhere such as a controller or model

Comment: @user574632 it is for templating only. Obviously if the header file changed location then I dont want to update 40 odd files :)